# jQuery initialising draggable on php generated li via loop not working

Tags: jquery, loops, draggable

Im using jQuery UI's draggable (http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and sortable (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) to create a drag and drop sorting page.

I use php to access the data stored in the database and print it out as an ul, giving each li an id (ids start at #draggable1 and progress through (#draggable2, #draggable3 etc) so every li has a unique id.

```
echo("<li id='draggable$count' class='ui-state-default'>");
```

I'm having trouble turning these li's into draggable objects, here's my jquery code below

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    var count = document.getElementById(‘count’).value;
    for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++){
        $("#draggable"+i).draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
        });
    }
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});
```

I have a hidden field containing the total number of li's displayed (currently 11), which var count grabs to use in the loop below it...however the loop does not seem to be running, any ideas?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Specify a position to li and check it.

Comment: sorry, could you please be a bit more specific?